# How can i import chinese data from excel to mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I'm a excel file where i've Chinese content and i want to import them into my tables.

My table is set utf-8 collation and my excel sheet has three worksheets.

When i tried to convert the worksheet into csv file and use them for import but when i opened the csv file it doesn't have the chinese characters properly..

And i tried to convert them into txt file and then import and nothing seems to be working..

How can i import chinese content into my mysql table?

### Update:

I tried your answers but didn't work on my way.. So i asked for a new file from the client from his native os.
My client sent me the .csv file with chinese data, when i opened it in excel, it has some odd characters but when i opened it using dreamweaver it showed the chinese characters.

When i tried to import data using `load data` it has the same weird characters inside the db .. Then i uploaded the file to the server and tried into insert into db using php script , it also doesn't work..

The script i used

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  include("includes/config.php");
  db_connect();
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  $file = fopen("../file.csv", "r");
  $i = 0;
  while (!feof($file)) {
      $arr = fgetcsv($file);
      $qry = "insert into tbl_wine_tasting_notes
    (`color` , `name` , `producer` , `vintage` , `size` , `country` , `region` ,
    `sub_region` , `comments` , `alcohol` , `points` , `varietals` ,
    `website`,`label`)
    values 
    ('" . implode("','", $arr) . "')";

      mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
      mysql_query($qry);
  }
  fclose($file);
?>
```

The qry statement was correct  when i echoed that but it didn't even inserted a single row..

What's wrong with this? I need them to upload them ..

Comment: Are you sure the Excel file IS encoded in UTF-8 or Unicode, and not BIG5 or GB?

Comment: Its not a big file and it just has 500 rows and when i open them in dreamweaver, i'm able to see the proper chinese characters..

Comment: Attention moderators: For this question the last two answers could be the correct and both will be a good solution, so i was confused to offer the bounty. So i upvoted and accepted one solution and offered bounty to the other.. For this kind of situation, where i want to felicitate both , what can be done? It will be good if can split the bounty , or if there is an option to offer my reputation to a user.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) to convert your .csv file *from* the major Chinese encodings below, transforming *to UTF-8*. The first '-f' from encoding that doesn't result in an error will be the correct encoding of your .csv file. From the command line on a system with iconv, try this:

```
iconv -f [Chinese encoding] -t UTF-8 [filename].csv > [filename]_utf8.csv
```

For the -f flag value, try:

1. CP936
2. GB18030
3. BIG-5

For example, I would guess that your .csv file was probably created on a Chinese Windows environment, so this could work:

```
iconv -f CP936 -t UTF-8 [filename].csv > [filename]_utf8.csv
```

You would then be able to open up [filename]_utf8.csv in a UTF-8 friendly text editor and see the Chinese displayed properly. It is this UTF-8 encoded [filename]_utf8.csv file that you would use to load the data into your database.

Comment: I accepted your answer as accepted answer. I had to make a choice with either you or kevin mooney , yours will be simple solution and you figured out the exact error(i.e file created from native os) and yours is a os based solution. But his will be useful for common php programmer who can work on any os.. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @kvijayhari, thanks. iconv is a handy tool in situations where you might be working with other character encodings. Good luck in your current task, hope it goes well!

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting data into a database that has a UTF-8 encoding, you need to be sure that you're inserting a string that is encoded in UTF-8.  Like buruzaemon said, your CSV file is probably encoded in CP936, BIG-5 or GB18030.

You can convert from one encoding to another in PHP by using mb_convert_encoding(str, to, [from]).  Since we're not sure which encoding the file is in, we can attempt to auto-detect it this way:

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  include("includes/config.php");
  db_connect();
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
  $file = fopen("../file.csv", "r");
  $i = 0;
  while (!feof($file)) {

    $arr = fgetcsv($file);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $item) { 
       $arr[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($item, 'UTF-8', 'CP936, GB18030, BIG-5');
    }

      $qry = "insert into tbl_wine_tasting_notes
      (`color` , `name` , `producer` , `vintage` , `size` , `country` , `region` ,
       `sub_region` , `comments` , `alcohol` , `points` , `varietals` ,
       `website`,`label`)
        values 
      ('" . implode("','", $arr) . "')";

    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query($qry);
 }
 fclose($file);
?>
```

You can see the docs for mb_convert_encoding here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Answer (score 0):

1. export it to csv from excel,
2. use text editor like notepad++ to
   change encoding to UTF-8 without
   DOM,
3. import to db via phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could do direct xls data import with a Data Import tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Command-line is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Other than suggesting you may be reading unicode not utf8, I can't comment on the charset issue. *However* an alternate approach might work.

I've found [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net/) to be useful for working directly with Excel files. A big plus is that it's a pure PHP implementation, so will run as happily on a *NIX or Mac server as a Windows machine with Excel.